# Using J2ME, is there away to programmatically send phone calls right to voicemail?

Tags: java-me

I'm writing an App for a specific phone that support J2ME. It will Run in background as a service. I need the ability to pop to the foreground from service based on an event and redirect any incoming calls to voice mail.

Comment: Maybe your 'specific phone' has an OEM API that allows this.

Answer (score 1):

May as well forget it. No way to achieve anything like this with J2ME.